# Creating a variable number of new ActiveRecord records at once Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a concept called `Transactions`. Each transaction can consist of a specific `number_of_stocks`- say 10.

What I'm now looking at doing, is creating a new record (`Share`) for each of that `number_of_stocks`.

Example: If `@transaction.number_of_stocks` = 10 then we should create 10 new records of Share.

The code below works if I just create one at a time, but I haven't found a way to create a variable number of new records depending on the `@transaction.number_of_stocks` variable.

In addition, and to make things trickier - each `Share` has an attribute `share_number`. What I would like to do is that for each new Share record created, the share_number should increment, *but* it should also check if there are any existing share_numbers belonging to the cap-table already, and "start there".

Just for context, I'll probably wrap this functionality into a `TransactionsHelper` somewhere so I can use it elsewhere.

```
@number_of_share_numbers_to_create = @transaction.number_of_stocks # Example: 10

Share.create( #TODO: Now we need to create 10 records here 
  owner_id: params[:buying_shareholder_id], 
  captable_id: @transaction.captable.id, 
  company_id: @transaction.company.id, 
  share_number: #TODO: Increment based on the latest share_number linked to this captable and then for each new record in this transaction 
)
```

The model

```
class Share < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :captable
    belongs_to :company
end
```

Comment: is `number_of_stocks` a column of `Transaction`?

Comment: yes of column type `decimal`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to look at the [times](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Integer.html#method-i-times) method on `Integer`. Something, perhaps, like:

```
@transaction.number_of_stocks.times do |i|
  Share.create( #TODO: Now we need to create 10 records here 
    owner_id: params[:buying_shareholder_id], 
    captable_id: @transaction.captable.id, 
    company_id: @transaction.company.id, 
    share_number: #TODO: Increment based on the latest share_number linked to this captable and then for each new record in this transaction 
  )    
end
```

If `number_of_stocks` is really a `decimal` and not an `integer`, as you state in your comment above, then you'll need to fiddle in order to make `times` work and to manage fractional `shares`. But, that's a different issue.

As an aside, will you always be transacting only stocks? What about other asset forms (e.g., bonds), derivatives (e.g., options), or other transactable assets/instruments? If at some point you will be transacting other assets/instruments, you might want to think about that now. Just a thought.

Comment: This performs 10 separate inserts. It would be much better to prepare 1 insert with 1 value sets, but it gets a bit more complicated.

Comment: Thanks for this. Perhaps I'll just use like `@transaction.number_of_stocks.to_i` so I can use the times method. Never actually knew that existed - thank you! Regarding the share_number concept, perhaps I can just query the "latest/largest?" number above and then do something like `share_number: @latest_share_number++` or similar! Thanks again!

Comment: @MarcinKołodziej - Yes, indeed. I decided to answer with the brute force approach. But, yes.

Comment: That `.times` solution worked well thanks @jvillian. Will keep working on the second piece of the puzzle!

Comment: Agree, would be interesting to see how to make this more efficient with 1 insert.

Comment: You'll want to be careful with using `to_i` as it will round down and you may end up short by one share.

Comment: @JP89 there are many good examples (and even gems perhaps) of preparing sql queries for ActiveRecord to insert multiple records with one query, unless it becomes a specific problem, you should try to refer to the already written sources for that :)

Comment: There are some gems like https://github.com/cph/activerecord-insert_many or https://github.com/bjhaid/active_record_bulk_insert to do multiple inserts at once on the database, it will be much faster. Be careful though, records won't trigger callbacks this way.

Comment: Thx for the tips!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the `share_number` piece with the following

A quick method to get the latest `share_number`

```
    def get_latest_share_number_from_captable(captable)
        @captable = Captable.find(captable.id)
        @shares = @captable.shares
        @share_numbers = []

        @shares.each do |s| 
            @share_numbers.push(s.share_number)
        end

        @latest_share = @share_numbers.max
        return @latest_share
    end
```

Then I use that method and the `.times` solution suggested in order to create new records.

```
# Add share numbering for this transaction
@number_of_share_numbers_to_create = @transaction.number_of_stocks.to_i

# Get last sharenumber in captable 
@latest_share = get_latest_share_number_from_captable(@transaction.captable)

@number_of_share_numbers_to_create.times do |i|
  Share.create(
    owner_id: params[:buying_shareholder_id], 
    captable_id: @transaction.captable.id, 
    company_id: @transaction.company.id, 
    share_number: @latest_share += 1 #Increment for each new record 
  )
end
```

Comment: How about `Captable.find(captable.id).shares.pluck(:share_number).max` instead of all that overhead? If you really want to do the array bit, then `Captable.find(captable.id).shares.map(&:share_number).max`, but I don't see what benefit that gives you.

Comment: There's a `maximum(:share_number)` method, you can even skip the `pluck`. `@captable.shares.maximum(:share_number)`

Comment: Wow that is way cleaner :) Thank you both!